# How do I play a stream of an online M4A/AAC audio file in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

Are there any libraries that exist that take in a URL as input, and starts playing the audio of the file?

I've tried AudioStreamer, but I run into ARC problems. I've also tried a couple of other libraries, but they don't seem to allow AAC files (only mp3).

Answer (score 1):

`<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` and AVPlayer can help you.
AVPlayer the best solution for playing file in queue.

Comment: `AVQueuePlayer` is the best solution for playing files in a queue.

Comment: @jsd, did not know about this one :)